# How to hide, obfuscate, or mask emails AND phone numbers in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, obfuscation

Is it possible to hide, obfuscate, or mask emails AND phone numbers in Wordpress natively?  Or is it necessary to use a plugin for this?  I need to be able to do this in my content and widget areas without modifying my theme or creating a child theme.

Comment: Why bother? Spambots get around these sorts of things easily.

Comment: If as stated, you cannot amend your theme or create a child theme, a plugin is your best option. Stuff like this belongs in a plugin anyhow. But as mentioned by @ceejayoz ... they will get round it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the http://hivelogic.com/enkoder/

I.e., the email `joe@example.com` (with that email as both link text and title; and the script also includes the subject line "Email") becomes the script below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<!--
var x="function f(x){var i,o=\"\",l=x.length;for(i=0;i<l;i+=2) {if(i+1<l)o+=" +
"x.charAt(i+1);try{o+=x.charAt(i);}catch(e){}}return o;}f(\"ufcnitnof x({)av" +
" r,i=o\\\"\\\"o,=l.xelgnhtl,o=;lhwli(e.xhcraoCedtAl(1/)3=!35{)rt{y+xx=l;=+;" +
"lc}tahce({)}}of(r=i-l;1>i0=i;--{)+ox=c.ahAr(t)i};erutnro s.buts(r,0lo;)f}\\" +
"\"(0)11\\\\,i\\\"kalf-sgs67y;93>$)37501\\\\\\\\\\\\+\\\\\\\"&\\\\hu25\\\\0%" +
"\\\\%(!k2/!,[GY}PT33\\\\0d\\\\\\\\nS\\\\@YFZ21\\\\02\\\\02\\\\\\\\BsMDoF24\\"+
"\\0\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\D\\\\OCVF6Q03\\\\\\\\pM3}wytjoyUs|q+x77\\\\1{\\\\dbfmU(a" +
"5wc#l=c\\\"\\\\\\\\\\\\3V02\\\\\\\\20\\\\06\\\\03\\\\\\\\16\\\\00\\\\02\\\\" +
"\\\\\\\\n0\\\\00\\\\\\\\1X00\\\\\\\\32\\\\06\\\\02\\\\\\\\37\\\\04\\\\00\\\\"+
"\\\\23\\\\00\\\\00\\\\\\\\\\\\n\\\\\\\\(\\\"}fo;n uret}r);+)y+^(i)t(eAodrCh" +
"a.c(xdeCoarChomfrg.intr=So+7;12%=;y=iy+0)11==(iif){++;i<l;i=0(ior;fthnglex." +
"l=\\\\,\\\\\\\"=\\\",o iar{vy)x,f(n ioctun\\\"f)\")"                         ;
while(x=eval(x));
//-->
//]]>
</script>
```

Or, for an automated solution: https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-enkoder/ The source for that is at https://github.com/mgree/phpenkoder

Some scrapers and bots can probably get around this method, but I've had good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do it without editing your theme or using a plugin.

There's a WordPress function called [antispambot()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/antispambot) which converts email addresses to HTML entities in the source code, e.g.

`&#106;&#111;h&#110;&#46;&#100;&#111;&#101;&#64;mysit&#101;.&#99;&#111;&#109;`

That Codex page I've linked to gives an email of using it to add a shortcode so less technical users can conceal email addresses.

I don't know of anything for telephone numbers.

As others have said, it's not hard to get round this sort of thing programmatically - in my opinion you're better off improving your spam filter than trying to hide the addresses.